# Save to Excel From JasperViewer

Tags: excel, jasper-reports

I'm using `JasperViewer` to show the report to the user and to be able to export to `pdf`, `word` and `Excel`.
The problem is while saving to `Excel`, and error prompts saying:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRXlsExporter, 
method: createMergeRegion signature: (Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRExporterGridCell;IILorg/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle;)V) Incompatible argument to function
        at net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRSingleSheetXlsSaveContributor.save(JRSingleSheetXlsSaveContributor.java:104)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewerToolbar.btnSaveActionPerformed(JRViewerToolbar.java:407)
```

Here's the code I'm using to show my report:

```java
  public void showReport() throws SQLException {


        RNVehicle rnVehicle = new RNVehicle();
        vehicles.clear();
        vehicles= rnVehicle.getVehiculos();

        //Path to your .jasper file in your package
        String reportName = "reports/ReportVehicles.jasper";

        //Get a stream to read the file
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(reportName);

        try {

            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(vehicles));

            //Viewer for JasperReport
            JRViewer jv = new JRViewer(jp);

            //Insert viewer to a JFrame to make it showable
            JFrame jf = new JFrame();
            jf.getContentPane().add(jv);
            jf.validate();
            jf.setVisible(true);
            jf.setSize(new Dimension(1020, 755));
            jf.setLocation(0, 0);
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I'm desperate :( , why is not running? What changes should I make? Or what libraries should I import to the project to make it run?

At the moment I have: `poi-3.6.jar` (the one that comes with the JR distribution), I also tried with previous versions, 3.5 and 3.2 and with all of them everything works fine, but just for html, pdf and word, not for Excel.

Any insight on this regard will be helpful.

Comment: I don't think this will solve your immediate problem, but from my read of the JR documentation, there is no need to get a stream to read the .jasper file. You can pass the file directly as a parameter so long as the variable points directly to the file. I.e. just pass reportName to the JasperFillManager.fillReport().

Comment: Could you post a link to the JavaDoc for JRXlsExporter?

Comment: that's what I did,but I haven't got any reply yet

Answer (score 2):

You need to add "poi-3.10.1.jar" in your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get it into a CSV and open it in notepad++ or something similar, do a find and replace for ,, (two commas in a row) and replace it with something like a dash as a place holder.  That's messed me up before.  after that, you can pull it into an array in the language of your choice and manipulate it from there.

Answer (score 0):

for Excel exporting needed jxl library.
Commonly JasperReports want commons-collections, commons-beanutils and commons-digester

Answer (score 0):

As Adel said, works good with specific "poi-3.10.1.jar" version.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>                        
    </dependency>
```